# Unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *guid.GUID

Tags: sql-server, go, guid

I work with Golang and SQL Server.
My struct in Golang:

```
type Role struct {
Id          guid.GUID `gorm:"primaryKey;column:Id;type:uniqueidentifier" json:"id"`
RoleName    string    `gorm:"column:RoleName;not null;unique" json:"roleName"`
IsEnable    bool      `gorm:"column:IsEnable" json:"isEnable"`
Permissions []RolePermission }
```

I use gorm to query data but receive error:

> unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *guid.GUID.

I used uuid before but the id data is wrong when query (guid to uuid).

Is any way to store and work with Guid using Golang and SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Early versions of go-gorm ([v0.2](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/commit/3cb95264dff572434ed72977d78f16ab4fe1dc83)) were including [UUID/GUID support for SQLTag](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/3cb95264dff572434ed72977d78f16ab4fe1dc83/postgres.go#L26-L58), with [`isUUID()`](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/3cb95264dff572434ed72977d78f16ab4fe1dc83/postgres.go#L72-L79) a test on the type name ("uuid" or "guid").

But that code is no longer present in current [go-gorm v2.0](https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html).

You might need to implement a [custom  Data Type Scanner / Valuer](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Implements-Customized-Data-Type), or use one like [`google/uuid`](https://github.com/google/uuid):

```golang
import (
  "github.com/google/uuid"
  "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Post struct {
  ID     uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
  Title  string
  Tags   pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]"`
}
```